# How to hit test shapes in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, geometry, 2d

I need the ability to determine which Shape a given point falls within.  There will be overlapped shapes and I need to find the Shape with the smallest area.  For example, given the Shapes and points illustrated in the image below the following would be true:

- Point 3 - collides with star
- Point 2 - collides with diamond
- Point 1 - collides with circle

[image]

Given this, I would like to know if there is a built in way to do what is needed.

Comment: you have already seen this one right? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309564(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It doesn't look like anything here is going to help me in this scenario since I need something that is handled independently of a mouse click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've arrived at a solution that meets the requirements, still interested in hearing if there is a better way of doing this.  My approach is as follows: do a hit-test by bounding box, then a geometric hit test based on the type of geometry.

For Polygons, I've adapted the C code mentioned http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes /pnpoly.html to work in C#.

```
int pnpoly(int nvert, float *vertx, float *verty, float testx, float testy)
{
  int i, j, c = 0;
  for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
    if ( ((verty[i]>testy) != (verty[j]>testy)) &&
     (testx < (vertx[j]-vertx[i]) * (testy-verty[i]) / (verty[j]-verty[i]) + vertx[i]) )
       c = !c;
  }
  return c;
}
```

For Ellipses, I've adaptated this code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231172%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

```
BOOL CCircCtrl::InCircle(CPoint& point)
{
    CRect rc;
    GetClientRect(rc);
    GetDrawRect(&rc);

    // Determine radii
    double a = (rc.right - rc.left) / 2;
    double b = (rc.bottom - rc.top) / 2;

    // Determine x, y
    double x = point.x - (rc.left + rc.right) / 2;
    double y = point.y - (rc.top + rc.bottom) / 2;

    // Apply ellipse formula
    return ((x * x) / (a * a) + (y * y) / (b * b) <= 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are drawing these shapes manually, you could do a second drawing pass into a separate buffer, and instead of drawing the shape, you write an ID into the buffer if the pixel is within the shape.  Then your hit test just has to index into that buffer and retrieve the ID.  You would get to re-use your drawing code completely, and it scales much better when you have more shapes, vertices, and hits to test.

Comment: Interesting but screen resolution dependent

Comment: I am not drawing manually, rather using elements derived from Shape.